# PHP: Cancel/Delete Subscription Not working in MTN DEP

Tags: php

We are using the MTN PHP-SDK from the below URL

https://github.com/digitalmaterial/dep.api.auth.php

Code:

```
$path = '/subscription/' . $subscription_id;
$depClient = new MTNDEP\DEPClient($accessKey, $accessSecret, $apiKey, $baseUrl);
$requestBody = [];
$response = $depClient->createRequest(MTNDEP\DEPClient::DELETE, $path, null, $requestBody)->send();
$responseArray = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Response:

```
Client error: `DELETE https://api.dep.mtn.co.za/subscription/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"message":"No method found matching route subscription/ for http method DELETE."}
```

We are unable to find any MTN-DEP Cancel subscription PHP code. Please help us and let us know how can we delete the subscription from MTN end?

Comment: What API documentation are you working off of? Both https://developers.mtn.com/products/mtn-subscription-api-v1 and the v2 counterpart suggest, that the customer ID needs to be supplied in the path as well. (If that's what you are trying to achieve, unsubscribe a specific customer from a subscription?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have noticed 2 things : 
1- in the mentioned documentation, the request sent like this 
`$depClient->createRequest('POST' '/subscription');`
so i think you need to use this , please try to adhere with all steps

```php
$depClient->createRequest('DELETE',$path); // Returns DEPClient object for chaining, see below
$depClient->getRequest(); // Will return the GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request object with signed auth details for DEP API requests 
$response       = $depClient->send();
$statusCode     = $response->getStatusCode(); // returns the http status code
$rawResponse    = (string) $response->getBody(); // body, you will need to cast to string or echo to get the body data.
$responseArray  = json_decode($rawResponse, true); // return json decode array.
```

2- make sure the `$subscription_id` is set and have a value before you send the request.

Answer (score 1):

Stating to the documentation, you need to specify the *customer ID* and the *subscription ID*.

You have to make a DELETE request to the endpoint `/customers/{id}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}`.

Maybe the path specified in your code should look like this:

```php
$path = '/customers/' . $customer_id . '/subscriptions/' . $subscription_id;

$depClient = new MTNDEP\DEPClient($accessKey, $accessSecret, $apiKey, $baseUrl);
$requestBody = [];
$response = $depClient->createRequest(MTNDEP\DEPClient::DELETE, $path, null, $requestBody)->send();
$responseArray = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Comment: We don't have any customer ID. Where we will get this?

Comment: Hi Dan, As per your instruction I have added customers id and get below error. 

`Client error: DELETE https://api.dep.mtn.co.za/customers/123456789/subscription/1234567890 resulted in a 404 Not Found response:
{"message":"No method found matching route customers/123456789/subscription/1234567890 for http method DELETE."}`